# Can't get array declared

Tags: arrays, ios

I want to make a simple picture display with a next button. I followed this code:

```
NSArray *pics2;
pics2=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:

      [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.jpg"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.jpg"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.jpg"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.jpg"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.jpg"],
      nil
      ];
NSLog(@"%i",[pics2 count]);
for (int i=0;i<[pics2 count]; i++){
    [foto setImage:[pics2 objectAtIndex:i]];
}
[pics2 release];
```

And then after the @synthesize the IBAction.

```
-(IBAction) prox:(id)sender {

 static int i=0;
 if(i==8)
     i=0;
 [foto setImage:[pics2 objectAtIndex:i]];
```

But I'm getting the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'pics2'.
Where am I supposed to declare the array 'pics2'?

Answer (score 1):

You are releasing pics2 before using it. If you want pics2 to be available to all functions of your class then make it as a private variable in the header file.

Define the `NSArray *pics2;` in the `.h` file. Don't release it after creating, release it only in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: Ok, so I declared and it worked for the first click, not for the followings.

Comment: I wonder if the NSLog is in the correct place. Shouldn't it be on the Action of the button?

Comment: maybe you can check if the value of `i` is getting updated. I think from your code, `i` will always be 0 in the IBAction method

Comment: Daniel, you appear to be setting the animation images in your init method already ([foto setImage:[pics2 objectAtIndex:i]], in your for loop). But then in your event handler method you are setting it again using a static counter that you never increment. If you could state what you are trying to achieve we could help with the logic.